# Official C/C++ Package Manager?

Tags: c++, c, package-manager

I would like to know whether there is an officially-mandated or recognized C/C++ Package Manager.

Comment: Conan is a package manager.

Comment: There is no offial one, no standard describes it. But I think conan is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

As @peterh describes in a comment, neither C nor C++ have an official package manager for libraries, modules or headers. This is different from languages like Rust (with the Cargo package manager) or Ruby (with Gems).

Also, C and C++ are very different languages, despite their having common "ancestry", and I would not conflate managing packages for both of them ... although others don't necessarily share my opinion on the matter.

Finally, C++20 will introduce modules into the language, creating an entirely new space of potential packaging of C++ artifacts - but which obviously has not yet been developed and explored.

See also [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/75671/a-c-package-manager) here on the site regarding **unofficial** C++ package managers.