# A C++ package manager

Tags: c++, package-manager

Many languages have associated package managers, and official online package repositories; but C++ doesn't seem to have one. Still, does it have any popular, non-official but robust, featureful and multi-platform package managers catering to it?

Note: I'm not talking about OS distribution packages.

Answer (score 1):

### Conan

A popular C++ package manager I am aware is Conan.

[Main website](https://conan.io/) | [GitHub repo](https://github.com/conan-io/conan) | [Documentation](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/)

It's by a company called [JFrog](https://jfrog.com/), which has a freemium service named the "Artifactory"; the binary packages of Conan are somehow related to / stored within the free part of the "Artifactory". There are, supposedly, around 180,000 binary packages accessible with Conan (likely including redundancies and versions of the same package etc.)

Main features:

- Libre
- Gratis
- Multi-platform
- Not officially condoned, but regarded favorably and featured in some C++ conferences.
- Interaction with "JFrog Artifactory", for non-source artifact packages.
- Uses the Python language internally
- No single central repository - everyone can be their own Conan node / repository.
- Versioning is per package/library

Answer (score 0):

### Microsoft vcpkg

A package manager for both C and C++, from Microsoft. Focuses on sources rahter than binaries.

[Main website](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/vcpkg?view=vs-2019) | [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg) | [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vcpkg) | [FAQ](https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/about/faq/)

- Libre: MIT license
- Gratis
- Source only (?)
- Platforms: MacOS, Windows, Linux
- Centralized repository
- Written in C++, not Python